# Create an object of arrays with their corresponding winners

Tags: javascript, arrays

say I have an array:

```
let array = [
  { win: "Ali", loser: "Jake"},
  { win: "carl", loser: "Dean"},
  { win: "Eli", loser: "Jake"},
  { win: "Eli", loser: "carl"},
  { win: "Ali", loser: "carl"},
  { win: "carl", loser: "Dean"},
  { win: "Dean", loser: "Eli"}
];
```

output should be:

```
{
  'Ali': ['Jake', 'carl'],
  'Jake':   [],
  'carl': ['Dean'],
  'Dean':  ['eli'],
  'eli': ['Jake', 'carl'],
}
```

So my first step is to create an empty array of all the winners inside of an object. Then push each element of winner with their corresponding loser. But I'm a bit lost on the approach. 
What I have:

```
function winner(array) {
  let newObj = {};

  for (let obj of array) {
    newObj[obj.winner] = [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more how the input gets turned into the output? The process isn't very clear

Comment: @CertainPerformance just made the edit basically need to output winners and their losers

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what your code is supposed to do? How did you determine the output from the array? It isn't clear.

Comment: Why is `carl` included in the `Ali` array in the output? (Ali did not win over carl in the input)

Comment: Is Ali supposed to be eli?

Comment: @CertainPerformance you're right. I fixed the output.

Comment: @inavda yes. fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = [
  { win: "Ali", loser: "Jake"},
  { win: "carl", loser: "Dean"},
  { win: "Eli", loser: "Jake"},
  { win: "Eli", loser: "carl"},
  { win: "Ali", loser: "carl"},
  { win: "carl", loser: "Dean"},
  { win: "Dean", loser: "Eli"}
];

const result = {};
for (let obj of array) {
if(result[obj.win] && !result[obj.win].includes(obj.loser)){
    result[obj.win].push(obj.loser);
}
else{
    result[obj.win] = [obj.loser];
}
if(!result[obj.loser])
    result[obj.loser] = [];      
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by taking an object as result set and build a new property for winner and loser. Add the loser to the winner array.

```js
var array = [{ win: "Ali", loser: "Jake" }, { win: "carl", loser: "Dean" }, { win: "Eli", loser: "Jake" }, { win: "Eli", loser: "carl" }, { win: "Ali", loser: "carl" }, { win: "carl", loser: "Dean" }, { win: "Dean", loser: "Eli" }],
    winner = array.reduce((r, { win, loser }) => {
        (r[win] = r[win] || []).push(loser);
        r[loser] = r[loser] || [];
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(winner);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
function winner(array) {
  let result = {};
  for (let obj of array) {
    result[obj.winner] = [];
    result[obj.loser] = [];
  }

  for (let obj of array) {
    if (!result[obj.winner].includes(obj.loser)) {
      result[obj.winner].push(obj.loser);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple :

```js
let scoreboard = [
    { winner: "Ali",  loser: "Jake" },
    { winner: "Carl", loser: "Dean" },
    { winner: "Eli",  loser: "Jake" },
    { winner: "Eli",  loser: "Carl" },
    { winner: "Ali",  loser: "Carl" },
    { winner: "Carl", loser: "Dean" },
    { winner: "Dean", loser: "Eli"  }
];

let winners = {};

scoreboard.forEach(competition => {
    if(!winners[competition.winner])
        winners[competition.winner] = [];
    winners[competition.winner].push(competition.loser);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KaKi87/w0bzm3La/)

PS : I added a line to prevent duplicate loser, but that's not very logical I think.

PPS : I don't create a winner entry for players who didn't won a competition, but if that's what you want too, I guess this data representation is not the right one.